# how can i change the value of the x and y in if(ab) at getArrow() locally

Tags: java, class, int

```
public class Arrow {
protected  static int x;
protected  static int y;

public void setA(boolean a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public void setB(boolean b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public void setAb(boolean ab) {
    this.ab = ab;
}

public Arrow( int x1, int y1) {
   this.x=x1;
    this.y=y1;
}
public double getySpeed(){

    return (-ySpeed*Time+Time*Time/10);
}
public boolean getX(){
    return x +Math.abs(xSpeed * Time)<canvasWidth-90;
}
public boolean getY(){
    return y+getySpeed()<canvasHeight-110;
}

public Matrix getArrow(){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();//1140,540

    matrix.postRotate((int)getAngle(), arrowWidth/2, arrowHeight / 2);
    if (a&&!ab) {
       // here if i do sout(x) it will show 75 which is the value i gave it in the constructor
        return a(x);
    }
   if(b&&!ab){
        // here if i do sout(y) it will show 125 which is the value i gave it in the constructor
       return (b(y));
    }
    if(ab){
            x =x+(int) Math.abs(xSpeed * Time);
            y = y+(int)getySpeed();
            matrix.postTranslate(x,y );
        }
    return matrix;
}
public Matrix b(int yy ){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate((int)getAngle(), arrowWidth/2, arrowHeight / 2);
    matrix.postTranslate(canvasWidth-90,yy );

    return matrix;
}
public Matrix a(int xx ){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate((int)getAngle(), arrowWidth/2, arrowHeight / 2);
    matrix.postTranslate(xx,canvasHeight-100 );

    return matrix;
}
```

I am trying to make a Bitmap arrow stop from leaving the screen so I figured out the maximum x and y coordinates and the arrow moves until it reaches these coordinates.

In `getArrow()`, at the `if(ab)` block, what I think I am doing is changing `x` and `y`, but in reality, they're not changing.
 - They stay the same value I gave them in the constructor.

How can I change the `x` and `y` in the class to the value I gave them at
`if(ab)` in `getArrow()`

Thank you :*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the issue you are facing is because you have declared `x` and `y` as `static` making them class variables which means their values will be the same for all objects.

```
protected  static int x;
protected  static int y;
```

Just remove the term, `static` from their declaration.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.